# Dying person is the last in his race of warriors, trying to find the people who killed his race

Tags: story-identification, books

All I remember is a guy who is dying from some kind of radiation, and is trying to find and punish the murderer of his race. He is the last of his kind, and has extreme fighting training, and is one of the best from his race. His race was made up of warriors, and could fight and beat nearly any foe. I think the protagonist was called Keith, or Kyle. He has a ship, and some battle equipment, and, if I remember correctly, a pet of some sort. The enemy was an organization called Darkwing or something similar. I can't remember much more, but I liked the books (it was a series) and really want to find it again!

Comment: The ultimate warrior, the paragon of a race of warriors, the last of his kind, is called **Keith**?!

Comment: Oh, I swear this is a dupe of something I saw recently.  I remember the book(s).  He is saved from radiation poisoning and his bones replaced with something unbreakable by an alien race which helps him, and he is aided in his tasks by one of those aliens who is a big telepathic bird thingy.  His planet basically hired themselves out as honorable mercenaries which is why they were all badass fighters. ARGH CAN'T FIND DUPE

Comment: i think that's it! are you sure you don't know what its called?

Answer (score 5):

GOT IT!

This is the [Last Legionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary) series.

The protagonist is Keill Randor.  The book *Galactic Warlord* covers the events you're talking about.

> [Keill's] home planet was destroyed by a malevolent entity known as
>   'The Warlord' whose sole aim is to spread war through the galaxy,
>   enabling him to rule over the remains that survive. The Warlord moved
>   against the Legions since he perceived them as the greatest threat to
>   his plan.

The enemy you're thinking of was in fact "a shadowy force known as the Deathwing".

His sidekick is Glr, "a telepathic avian life form from another galaxy."

He is saved from his lethal radiation poisoning by "The Overseers," who "replaced his entire skeleton - using an unbreakable alloy".  This plays into the conclusion of this book, where:

> The Deathwing attempt to kill or disable Keill by binding him and then inducing convulsions strong enough to break his back.  They believe they succeeded; however, his bones are unbreakable and they are deceived into thinking his back is broken and leave him unattended, etc. etc.

This is in fact a dupe in depth:

- [Young-adult science fiction novel series. Kid trained as warrior,
  all other kid warriors wiped out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63155/young-adult-science-fiction-novel-series-kid-trained-as-warrior-all-other-kid)
- [Need help identifying this 'space novel'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51763/need-help-identifying-this-space-novel)
- [Scifi book from the 80's. The last of a warrior race](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65329/scifi-book-from-the-80s-the-last-of-a-warrior-race/65330)

That said, I couldn't find them until I remembered and could search knowing the answer 8P.  So I'm kind of filling this answer out with keywords in case it helps someone find it in the future.

Comment: So not "keith" then?

Comment: Not only was he not "Keith", his sidekick was "Glr" and his best friend was "Oni".

Comment: Dupe of a dupe of a dupe of a dupe of a dupe of a dupe, I kid you not.

Comment: If you've tracked them down already, I invite you to edit and add the three dupes I missed - if we have to have a meta-dupe, why not make it a thorough meta-dupe?